# Find indexPath of UITableViewCell by label

Tags: swift, uitableview, if-statement, nsstring, xcode6

I have an UITableView which includes a few cells with tasks (label). I also have an array of type string which includes a few tasks which are displayed in the tableView. Now I want to check if an string from the array matches with an string from any cell. If it matches I wanna find out the indexPath of the matching cell.

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking about this wrong. You need to slap yourself on the side of the head and say Model-View-Controller loudly several times.

Cells don't have strings. They are just *views*. In a certain sense, cells don't even exist! That's a very real thing: in, say, a 100-row table, only about 12 cells may exist at any one time. So there are no cells to look in.

The strings are in your *model*, not your view. Stop thinking about the table and think about where the information about the *data* that goes into your table is stored. *That* is where you want to look for the string. And when you find it, you will *know* the index path, because that's how your model is structured.